# Specify composite key using Nhibernate.Mapping.Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How to specify composite key for an entity using Nhibernate Mapping Attributes.

Below is a sample entity with composite key. The keys here are : **InternalCompanyCode** and **CmAddress**.

Currently I am using the RawXml attribute to specify the composite key. But I want to specify it using Id or CompositeId or any other suitable attribute for this.

```
[Class(Table = "APVENDP")]
public class APVendor 
{
    [RawXml(Content = "<composite-id><key-property name=\"CmAddress\" type=\"int\" column=\"B5AOCD\" /><key-property name=\"InternalCompanyCode\" type=\"int\" column=\"B5COCD\" /></composite-id>")]
    public int InternalCompanyCode { get; set; }

    public int CmAddress { get; set; }

    [Property(Name="ContactNumber", Column = "B5AMCD", Precision = 3, Scale=0)]
    public int ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Property(Name="CurrencyCode", Column = "B5B3CD", Length = 4)]
    public String CurrencyCode { get; set; }

...

}
```

Comment: Tried options given in the following thread ? https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2376310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Put all keys at the top instead of decorating the fields"**

The solution is discussed at this forum: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2376310

**Example:**

```
[Class(Table = "APVENDP")]
public class APVendor
{
    [CompositeId(1)]
    [KeyProperty(2, Name = "CmAddress", Column = "B5AOCD")]
    [KeyProperty(3, Name = "InternalCompanyCode", Column = "B5COCD")]
    [Column(Name = "B5COCD")]
    private int? internalCompanyCode = 0;

    [Column(Name = "B5AOCD")]
    private int? cmAddress = 0;

    [Property(Name = "ContactNumber", Column = "B5AMCD", Precision = 3, Scale = 0)]
    [Column(Name = "B5AMCD")]
    private int? contactNumber = 0;

    [Property(Name = "CurrencyCode", Column = "B5B3CD", Length = 4)]
    [Column(Name = "B5B3CD")]
    private String currencyCode = "";

    ...
}
```

The credit for the answer goes to the comment made by [jbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236044/jbl)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Robin Rizvi answer, you also need to override entity's `Equals` and `GetHashCode` members.